# Kubernetes - User "system:serviceaccount:management:gitlab-admin" cannot get resource "serviceaccounts" in API >group "" in the namespace "services"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-rbac

I am getting this error -

> Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with >install: could not get information about the resource: serviceaccounts "simpleapi" is forbidden: >User "system:serviceaccount:management:gitlab-admin" cannot get resource "serviceaccounts" in API >group "" in the namespace "services"

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gitlab
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gitlab-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab
    namespace: kube-system
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab
    namespace: services
```

I am using this for RBAC as cluster-admin. Why am I getting this . I also tried the below but still got the same issue . Can someone explain what is that I am doing wrong here -

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: "ClusterRole"
metadata:
  name: gitlab-admin
  labels:
    app: gitlab-admin
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"] # also tested with ""
    resources:
      [
        "replicasets",
        "pods",
        "pods/exec",
        "secrets",
        "configmaps",
        "services",
        "deployments",
        "ingresses",
        "horizontalpodautoscalers",
        "serviceaccounts",
      ]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "patch", "delete", "update"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: "ClusterRoleBinding"
metadata:
  name: gitlab-admin-global
  labels:
    app: gitlab-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  kind: "ClusterRole"
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab-admin
    namespace: management
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab-admin
    namespace: services
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gitlab-admin
  namespace: management
  labels:
    app: gitlab-admin
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gitlab-admin
  namespace: services
  labels:
    app: gitlab-admin
```

Comment: when exactly you receive this error?

Answer (score 0):

So here is what happened . I needed to run this as inside the namespace i.e
I changed the config to run from the namespace management itself .

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=management
```

And then

```
kubectl apply -f gitlab-admin.yaml
```